# Orthographic camera and Stage

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using libgdx 1.1.

Is it possible set the orthographic camera for the Stage in scene2d? I need it to add button in my app and at the same time to support different screen resolution.

I've tried this code to adapt the screen:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, x, y);
batch = new SpriteBatch();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is not correct. Nowadays you create a [viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) depending on what you need. [(There are several)](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) While creating your stage you add the viewport to it. The viewport itself holds the camera. You can optain that camera by `getCamera()`

You create the viewport with your camera.

So here is how it could look like:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, x, y);
FitViewport viewp = new FitViewport(x, y, camera); // change this to your needed viewport
batch = new SpriteBatch();
Stage s = new Stage(viewp, batch); //also pass the singelton batch here. Try just to use onee batch to have a good performance.
```

Here is some further information out of the [libgdx forum about this.](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13912)